# Hats break formatting on mod elections page

Tags: bug, design, election, winter-bash

I know that mod elections and Winter Bash are spaced in time in general, but using a hat may break formatting on [elections page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-4748819):

> [image]

Comment: Well, simply don't visit election pages during winter bash. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... and all other buggy pages of SE. Just cut the Internet cord. ;)

Comment: That would be perfect fix for all bugs! :D

Comment: Just don't run elections during Winter bash.

Comment: @rene indeed, that never happens. All elections have been postponed until January.